# SVG circle animation controlled with dashoffset

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transitions

I'm trying to get an on hover transition on circle svg (not a full 360deg, just about 80%).

From my understanding, the below code should do, however for some reason, instead of just going to point zero, it adds additional mini arch. How to avoid that?

```css
.outer {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 204;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.8s;
}

svg:hover .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 204 !important;
}
```

```html
<svg width="90" height="90">
   <circle class="outer" cx="43" cy="43" r="40"/>
</svg>
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6vj81fmL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your initial `stroke-dasharray` is too short to cover the whole circumference of the circle.

The circumference seems to be `252` so give it an initial offset of `50` (approx 20%), then transition to an offset equal to the `stroke-dasharray`.

```css
.outer {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 252;
  stroke-dashoffset: 50;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.8s;
}

svg:hover .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 252 !important;
}
```

```html
<svg width="90" height="90">
    <circle class="outer" cx="43" cy="43" r="40"/>
</svg>
```